# Blender 2.79 Principled BSDF Shader + Substance Painter

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine

I want to have shiny paint on top of the metal material. I made a material in Substance Painter. If I use shaders from Andrew Price, I am able to achieve this effect. However if I try this with Principled shader, that shininess of the paint is gone. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Advice would be much appreciated, thank you.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Found a problem. Hopefully my mistakes can be useful to someone.

When you are in substance painter. Make sure to turn off properties of the material which a material doesn't have. In my case "Paint" doesn't have metallic property.

[image]